# Java regular expression for French names

Tags: java, regex

I need to modify regular expression to allow all standard characters, French characters, spaces AND dash (hyphen) but only one at a time.

What I have right now is:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class FrenchRegEx {

    static final String NAME_PATTERN = "[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-' ]+";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        //name = "Jean Luc"; // allowed
        //name = "Jean-Luc"; // allowed
        //name = "Jean-Luc-Marie"; // allowed
        name = "Jean--Luc"; // NOT allowed

        if (!Pattern.matches(NAME_PATTERN, name)) {
            System.out.println("ERROR!");
        } else System.out.println("OK!");
    }
}
```

and it allows 'Jean--Luc' as a name and that is not allowed.

Any help with this?
Thanks.

Comment: `[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]([-' ][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z])*`

Comment: Most of the letters in the `\u00C0-\u017F` range aren't used in French.

Comment: Obligatory link: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks, I shouldn't title question with "French names"

Comment: Other thing, accented letters can be coded in two different ways:  using a single unicode code point like U+00E2 (for â) or using a non accented letter (U+0061 a) + the combining character (U+0302 ^ combining circumflex accent).

Comment: To prevent problems related to combining characters, the best way isn't to describe them in the pattern but to normalize the string before testing it with the pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, you want a pattern which is a 0 or more hyphens, separated by 1 or more other characters. It's just a matter of writing the pattern that way:

```
"[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']+([- ][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']+)*"
```

This also assumes you don't want names to start or end with a hyphen or space, nor that you want more than one space in a row, and that you also want to disallow a space to follow or proceed a hyphen.

Comment: I'd move the apostrophe to the list of symbols that should not appear next to each other. I doubt the OP wants to match `De''s` or `Bob 'Ray`. The only questionable case to me is an apostrophe at the end of a name might be valid in some case.

Answer (score 4):

You need to disallow consecutive hyphens. You may do it with a negative lookahead:

```
static final String NAME_PATTERN = "(?!.*--)[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-' ]+";
                                    ^^^^^^^^
```

To disallow any of the special chars to be consecutive, use

```
static final String NAME_PATTERN = "(?!.*([-' ])\\1)[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z-' ]+";
```

Another way is to unroll the pattern a bit to match strings where the special char(s) can appear in between letters, but cannot appear consecutively (i.e. if you need to match `Abc-def'here` like strings):

```
static final String NAME_PATTERN = "[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]+(?:[-' ][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]+)*";
```

or to only allow 1 special char that can only appear in between letters (i.e. if you nee to only allow strings like `abc-def`, or `abc'def`):

```
static final String NAME_PATTERN = "[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]+(?:[-' ][\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]+)?";
```

Note that you do not need anchors here because you are using the pattern inside a `.matches()` method that requires a full string match.

NOTE: you may further tune the patterns by moving special chars that may appear anywhere in the string from the `[-' ]` character class to the `[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]` character classes, like `[\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z]`, but watch out for `-`. It should be placed at the end, near `]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `([\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']+[- ]?)+`. This would match one or more names separated by exactly one dash or space.

Comment: Note `([\u00C0-\u017Fa-zA-Z']+[- ]?)+` will also allow a `-` or space at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: the two first patterns in your answer allow it too.

Comment: Yes, I just note that.